# Generic linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, generics

I provided an [answer to a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50042818/generic-linked-list) about a generic linked list. I just had the curiosity of having my code peer-reviewed as I wrote the code specifically for the answer.

That is, I have not implemented a generic linked list before, and would like to see if there are minor issues with the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct node {
    void *data;
    node *next;
} node;


int lst_nodeAdd(
    node **head,
    node **tail,
    const void *data,
    size_t szData);

void lst_nodePrint(
    node *head,
    void(*print)(const void *));

void lst_nodeFree(node *head);

/* PRINTING FUNCTIONS */
void print_int(const void *a);
void print_string(const void *str);


int main(void)
{
    const char *str[] = {
        "0x0001",
        "0x0002",
        "0x0003",
    };

    // head & tail
    node *head = NULL;
    node *tail = NULL;

    // List of strings
    lst_nodeAdd(&head, &tail, str[0], strlen(str[0]) + 1);
    lst_nodeAdd(&head, &tail, str[1], strlen(str[1]) + 1);
    lst_nodeAdd(&head, &tail, str[2], strlen(str[2]) + 1);

    lst_nodePrint(head, print_string);
    lst_nodeFree(head);
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    //....................................................

    // List of ints
    int int_array[] = {
        0,
        1,
        2,
    };
    lst_nodeAdd(&head, &tail, &int_array[0], sizeof(int));
    lst_nodeAdd(&head, &tail, &int_array[1], sizeof(int));
    lst_nodeAdd(&head, &tail, &int_array[2], sizeof(int));

    lst_nodePrint(head, print_int);
    lst_nodeFree(head);
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}


int lst_nodeAdd(
    node **head,
    node **tail,
    const void *data,
    size_t szData)
{
    void *tmp;
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));

    if (!tmp)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ((node *)tmp)->next = NULL;
    ((node *)tmp)->data = malloc(szData);

    if (!((node *)tmp)->data)
    {
        free(tmp);
        return 0;
    }

    memcpy(((node *)tmp)->data, data, szData);

    if (!*head)
    {
        *head = (node *)tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        (*tail)->next = (node *)tmp;
    }
    *tail = (node *)tmp;
    return 1;
}

void lst_nodePrint(
    node *head,
    void(*print)(const void *))
{
    while (head)
    {
        print(head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
}

void lst_nodeFree(node *head)
{
    node *tmp = head;
    while (head)
    {
        head = head->next;
        free(tmp->data);
        free(tmp);
        tmp = head;
    }
}

void print_int(const void *a)
{
    printf("%d\n", *(const int *)a);
}

void print_string(const void *str)
{
    puts((const char *)str);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment

"implemented a generic linked list', this codes seems to be focused on adding to the list variant sizes of data - which in good for *strings*.  I would find this a bit error prone or tedious and prefer to provide the size at link-list head creation time, rather than provided it each time with `lst_nodeAdd()`.

## Major

### Invalid standard C code

`node` is not defined yet used in `node *next;`

```
typedef struct node {
    void *data;
    // node *next;
    struct node *next;
} node;
```

## Minor

### Odd use of `void *`

Every reason to use `node *tmp` and not `void *tmp` with all the unneeded casting.  I suspect this is another reflection of compiling to C++ rather than C.

```
// void *tmp;
// if (!*head) {
//     *head = (node *)tmp;
// }  else {
//     (*tail)->next = (node *)tmp;
// }  *tail = (node *)tmp;
node *tmp;
if (!*head) {
  *head = tmp;
} else {
  (*tail)->next = tmp;
}
*tail = tmp;
```

### Allocate to the size of the de-referenced type.

With above change, size to the variable, not its type.  Easier to code, review and maintain.

```
// tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
tmp = malloc(sizeof *tmp);
```

### The size of user data may be 0

Although strange, there is no reason to not support a size of 0.  Just need to modify the allocation check as a return of `NULL` from `malloc(0)` is OK.

```
// if (!((node *) tmp)->data) {
if (!((node *) tmp)->data && szData > 0) {
```

### Use `const`

For functions that do not change the referenced data, use `const` to better convey code's intent and applicability.

```
// void lst_nodePrint(node *head, void (*print)(const void *)) {
void lst_nodePrint(const node *head, void (*print)(const void *)) {
```

### Code *looks* wrong

```
  // OK, yet perhaps ...
  node *tmp = head;
  while (head) {
    head = head->next;
    free(tmp->data);
    free(tmp);
    tmp = head;
  }
  // ... this instead
  while (head) {
    node *next = head->next;
    free(head->data);
    free(head);
    head = next;
  }
```

### Missing header

Make a separate header file like `lst.h` to show what goes in there and not in the companion `lst.c`

### Implementation vs test separation

Move these test declarations and functions to another file or to the bottom of the post to show a clear demarcation of test code.

```
void print_int(const void *a);
void print_string(const void *str);
int main(void) { ...
```

## Other

Good code that avoids leak when only one allocation worked.

```
if (!((node *) tmp)->data) {
  free(tmp);
  return 0;
}
```

Perhaps more later.